# Получение текста из текущего элемента.Android

Tags: java, android, activity, textview

Есть обработчик нажатия на элемент, посредством которого происходит переход на новое Activity

В новом Activity есть toolbar, в котором  должен отображаться текст непосредственно полученный из нажатого элемента.

Есть кое-какой набросок, созданный при помощи Ютба, но работает не так как нужно. Т.е. суть в том, что есть список фильмов, - при нажатии на один из них открывается новое активити, содержащее инфу о фильме.

Главное активити :

```
public class HomeworkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final List<ToDoItems> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new ToDoItems ("Seven"),
            new ToDoItems ("Sleepy Hollow"),
            new ToDoItems ("House of Wax"),
            new ToDoItems ("From Hell")

    ));
    ToDoAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hw);

        adapter = new ToDoAdapter(this,list);
        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Item);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("My Film List");
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeworkActivity.this,DescriptionActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("FilmName",listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Вызываемое активити:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DescriptionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView image;
    Toolbar d_toolbar;
    EditText date;
    EditText ganre;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        d_toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
        ganre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ganre);
        String film= getIntent().getStringExtra("FilmName");

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            d_toolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString(film));
            if (d_toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Seven")) {
                image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DescriptionActivity.this,R.drawable.seven));
                date.setText("2000");
                ganre.setText("Thriller,Detective");
            }
            else if (d_toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Sleepy hollow")) {
                    image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DescriptionActivity.this,R.drawable.sleepy_holl));
                    date.setText("2000");
                    ganre.setText("Thriller,Horror");
            }
            else if (d_toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("House of wax")) {
                    image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DescriptionActivity.this,R.drawable.h_of_wax));
                    date.setText("2000");
                    ganre.setText("Horror");
            }
            else if (d_toolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("From hell")) {
                    image.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(DescriptionActivity.this,R.drawable.from_hell));
                    date.setText("2000");
                    ganre.setText("Thriller,Horror");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Раскройте подробнее "но работает не так как нужно".

Comment: Активити открывается,но в toolbar  просто высвечивается путь к самому проекту. Явно при нажатии на элемент нужно как то вытаскивать название фильма  и в строку d_toolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString(   )); помещать именно это название.

Comment: плюс к ответу. Из вашего списка выбирается одна позиция, вы поставили множественное выделение (CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE, вместо CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE). В вашем случае вообще нет необходимости использовать режим выделения, так как он используется для отметок пунктами чекбоксами.

Answer (score 1):

У вас много лишнего. Сделайте, например, так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeworkActivity.this, DescriptionActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FilmName", list.get(position));
startActivity(intent);
```

а потом так:

```
String filmName = getIntent().getStringExtra("FilmName");
d_toolbar.setTitle(filmName);
```

---

Ну и всё это надо в БД сложить, меж активити передавать ID записи, а не данные, ничего не хардкодить, пользовать `switch` вместо `if else` и правильно именовать переменные.

Comment: к сожалению ваш способ не помог

Comment: @Alice, мой способ правильный и рабочий. Вы что-то где-то как-то не так делаете. Но, пока вы не станете рассказывать что именно и как у вас не получилось вы не получите иного ответа. Ибо невозможно исправить правильный ответ без информации о том что именно у вас не получилось в его использовании в вашем коде.

Comment: ну проблема в том что теперь приложение вообще не запускается.а почему так,я понять не могу...

Comment: @Alice, смотрите в логи - там показана ошибка в виде названия, причины, стека вызовов и указания на строку падения. Если же это ошибка компиляции - то это в редакторе кода красным выделено.